# Drupal contextual block above view?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm using Drupal 7 along with the Views and Context modules. I have a particular view with a page display, and I want to put a particular block in the content region. When I do that, the block appears below the view.

I want the block to appear *above* the view, instead. Is this possible, or do I have to create another region to go above the content region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you mention in your question, you'll need a region above the content region for this. The default theme for Drupal 7, [Bartik](http://drupal.org/documentation/themes/bartik), has several such regions (the 'Featured' region is probably the closest to what you're after), so if you're making a custom theme, you can refer to that theme for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Go to edit your page view and click add on the header region. Navigate to your block view and insert it . 
 
This may be the quick solution as it will display the block directly above the page content. It also allows the option of inherit contextual filters so the  header display can receive the same contextual filters as its parent.
This can be also done in the footer region and works on all themes.